# Hazelcast instance is not active! (com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstanceNotActiveException). Message payload is of type: HashMap

Tags: java, mule, hazelcast, mule-cluster

I have implemented an service application in java with MuleSoft 3.5.1 that it works in cluster server, and sometimes I get an error "Hazelcast instance is not active!" and the all service are bloked, so I must restart both server to resolve the problem. The hazelcast-3.1.6.jar is in my project.

```
     ERROR 2015-06-22 09:39:00,425 [[gs_p_api_QA-vGS_P_0_1_18].http1_connector.receiver.06] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy:
*****************************************************************************
Message               : Hazelcast instance is not active! (com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstanceNotActiveException). Message payload is of type: HashMap
Code                  : MULE_ERROR-29999
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. Hazelcast instance is not active! (com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstanceNotActiveException)
  com.hazelcast.spi.impl.ProxyServiceImpl$ProxyRegistry:220 (null)
2. Hazelcast instance is not active! (com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstanceNotActiveException). Message payload is of type: HashMap (org.mule.api.MessagingException)
  org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor:32 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MessagingException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstanceNotActiveException: Hazelcast instance is not active!
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.ProxyServiceImpl$ProxyRegistry.<init>(ProxyServiceImpl.java:220)
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.ProxyServiceImpl$ProxyRegistry.<init>(ProxyServiceImpl.java:207)
        at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.ProxyServiceImpl$1.createNew(ProxyServiceImpl.java:69)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************
```

How can I resolve this problem definitively?

Comment: Cluster is an EE feature, you surely have MuleSoft a support contract. Haven't you tried contating support?

Comment: Yes, I asked them, but no response yet from support Mule.

Comment: Appearently HZ is being used after it has been shut down. Then you get this exception. The question of course is what happened.

Answer (score 2):

I hit the similar exception of "com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstanceNotActiveException: Hazelcast instance is not active!" when running a web app. In my case, it was caused by OutOfMemory, though it was not obvious initially.

I reckon you may have a memory issue, which causes the HashMap getting too large perhaps.

Comment: This is a bit vague.  You could improve this answer by including some guidance on investigating memory issues in Hazelcast.

Comment: It can explain the issue. If HZ runs into an OOME, it will shut down the HZ instance. If this is the case, it would be logged. Apart from that, also the health-monitor would kick in and start logging all kinds of metrics including the memory usage and gc statistics.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the error "Hazelcast instance is not active" is shown when Stash is not available due to out of memory errors.

https://confluence.atlassian.com/stashkb/stash-become-unresponsive-with-hazelcast-instance-is-not-active-726369931.html

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, link only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow, you can improve this answer by taking vital parts of the link and putting it into your answer, this makes sure your answer is still an answer if the link gets changed or removed :)

Comment: This answer is almost entirely orthogonal to answering the question - Stash is an Atlassian product, and the question asker is implementing their own software using Mulesoft.